# How to autostart gui application cross desktop?

Tags: autostart

I want to add my gui application to autostart, while remaining cross desktop.

[.xinitrc looked suitable, but it's not. KDE does not listen to it.](http://www.jon.demon.co.uk/kde_xinitrc/)

If possible, I'd like to prevent adding a custom autostart command for each desktop environment.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your application's `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart`.